# VS 2008 Service Pack 1 problem

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2008-sp1

My OPS is XP and service pack 3 installed.I cant install vs2008 service pack1,In log file i see  'Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Design-Time Components for x86 - KB947888' cant be installed. Error code is 1603.Last part of Installation file is here.

```
Returning IDOK. INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR 
[Error 1335.
    The cabinet file 'patch.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. 
    This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, 
    or a problem with this package.]
[1/12/2009, 10:14:50] 
   (IronSpigot::MsiExternalUiHandler::UiHandler) 
   Returning IDOK. INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART 
   [Action 10:14:50: Rollback. Rolling back action:]
[1/12/2009, 10:17:29]
   (IronSpigot::MspInstallerT<class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class ATL::StrTraitATL<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > >::PerformMsiOperation)
   Patch (C:\DOCUME~1\Cem\LOCALS~1\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1\VS90sp1-KB945140-X86-ENU.msp;
              C:\DOCUME~1\Cem\LOCALS~1\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1\VC90sp1-KB947888-x86-enu.msp) 
              install failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU). 
   Msi Log: 
      Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1_20090112_100005671-Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU-MSP0.txt
[1/12/2009, 10:17:29] 
    (IronSpigot::MspInstallerT<class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class ATL::StrTraitATL<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > >::PerformMsiOperation) 
    MsiApplyMultiplePatches returned 0x643
```

Comment: This isn't a programming-related question.

Comment: are you installing from a DVD or an ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error and the problem is that the iso file, even when corrupted (by an unstable download for instance) can still be uncompressed and/or mounted/burnt successfully.
I re-downloaded the iso, mounted the new one and installed with no problems... I then observed a difference in the md5 hash of the failing iso with the one that worked...
Make sure your vs2008 sp1 iso has this hashes to verify that a corrupted iso file is not the cause:

MD5 Hash = 0C5C6B7E4E80B66CD299B1DBA6A819DB

SHA-1 Hash = 2459232F67B38594DE192778020145DCD0B0DF9F

Comment: This was the answer for me. Seems my hard drive (Raid5 array) was having issues or something. I finally downloaded it on one of the file share servers here at work, and it finally had the MD5 checksum Rodolfo gives here.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded SP1, download again. It might also be that you don't have enough RAM in your machine for the installer to unpack the patch.

Answer (score 0):

No divo,i think the problem is depend on a program(Like a third party program) in my machine.I am downloading now sp as iso file.But i think that it wont fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the program is Accessing c:\config.msi folder andit is not get the priveliages.